# How to get data from database which is located on my computer. Android

Tags: android, database

I need a list of cities in my android application. And i already downloaded a database which contains needed information. Now i am looking for solution how to get this data from db and put it in arraylist or to make search in application by city name. What technologies i can use to solve this problem?

Comment: There are a number of solutions that come to mind. You could create a local server using easyphp. Create a mysql database on it and connect your application to the local server. You could also create a sqlite database and put your data in it. You can easily retrieve data from it in your app. There's firebase too. You could use that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the below options. Depends on your need. If you want to update the database dynamically i would suggest to go with Firebase(My personal choice). Good luck.

1. Locally using SQL Lite. (No Network Connection Needed) ([Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html))
2. WebServer (Network Connection Needed)
3. Couchbase (Network Connection Needed) ([Couchbase Documentation](https://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-server))
4. Firebase (Network Connection Needed) ([Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/))